# Obtener todos los arrays contenidos en un JsonArray

Tags: java, android, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

tengo el siguiente jsonArray que a su vez tiene varios arreglos contenidos, todos con las mismas etiquetas, pero al momento de iterar en el para poder guardar cada uno de sus arreglos en un arrayList de java pero solo puedo guardar el primer objeto o el primer array, este es mi Json solo con 2 arreglos de N.

```
[{"lngIdCitaComedor":154,"strNombre":"AMEYALLI VICTORIA SARMIENTO","fcSolicitudReservacion":1643090400000,"strHoraReservacion":"15:00 - 16:00 horas"},{"lngIdCitaComedor":153,"strNombre":"AMEYALLI VICTORIA SARMIENTO","fcSolicitudReservacion":1642572000000,"strHoraReservacion":"12:00 - 13:00 horas"}]
```

Este es el código con el que recorro mi JsonArray con un un Log para verificar cada salida

```
For(int i = 0; i < jsonArrReservations.length(); i++){
    objectInArray = jsonArrReservations.getJSONObject(i);
    Iterator key = objectInArray.keys();

    while (((Iterator<?>) key).hasNext()) {
         String k = key.next().toString();
         Log.e("","Key: "+k+" Objeto: "+objectInArray.getString(k));
         objectInArray = jsonArrReservations.getJSONObject(i);                            
    }
Log.e("Object i del JSON",objectInArray);
}
```

Pero solamente obtengo el primer arreglo

```
{"lngIdCitaComedor":154,"strNombre":"AMEYALLI VICTORIA SARMIENTO","fcSolicitudReservacion":1643090400000,"strHoraReservacion":"15:00 - 16:00 horas"}
```

La pregunta aquí es, como hago para saltar al siguiente arreglo en mi JsonArray, necesito llenar una tabla con los registros de reservación de cada persona. De antemano le agradezco su interés por esta duda.

**Solución**

Lo que hice fue guardar los valores de las keys que necesitaba de mi Json en Strings para que posteriormente los fuera agregando a un ArrayList.

```
try {
            String response = connection.execute().get();
            //********Convertir JsonArrayList en Arraylist
            JSONArray jsonArrReservations = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrReservations.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArrReservations.getJSONObject(j);
                String lngIdCitaComedor = objectInArray.getString("lngIdCitaComedor");
                String strFechaReservacion = objectInArray.getString("strFechaReservacion");
                String strHoraReservacion = objectInArray.getString("strHoraReservacion");
                String strEstatus = objectInArray.getString("strEstatus");
                String blnPermiteCancelar = objectInArray.getString("blnPermiteCancelar");

                listaReservations.add(new ReservationTO(lngIdCitaComedor,strFechaReservacion,
                        strHoraReservacion,strEstatus,blnPermiteCancelar));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No deberías tener problema para obtener todos los elementos, pero debes primeramente saber como esta estructurado tu json, recuerda que:

> Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.
>
> Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.

por lo tanto lo que tienes es un array json que contiene dos objetos json:

```
[{
    "lngIdCitaComedor": 154,
    "strNombre": "AMEYALLI VICTORIA SARMIENTO",
    "fcSolicitudReservacion": 1643090400000,
    "strHoraReservacion": "15:00 - 16:00 horas"
}, {
    "lngIdCitaComedor": 153,
    "strNombre": "AMEYALLI VICTORIA SARMIENTO",
    "fcSolicitudReservacion": 1642572000000,
    "strHoraReservacion": "12:00 - 13:00 horas"
}]
```

**Primeramente debes obtener el array** de esta forma (suponiendo que jsonResponse es la variable que contiene el json):

```
   JSONArray jsonArrReservations = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
```

**y posteriormente iteras para obtener sus objetos.**

Por cierto, es importante definir una etiqueta cuando imprimas al LogCat de otra forma esto no imprimiría información:

```
 Log.e("","Key: "+k+" Objeto: "+objectInArray.getString(k));
```

---

Este seria el código (suponiendo que `jsonResponse` es tu json):

```
        try {

            //*Crea JSONArray a partir de la respuesta. 
            JSONArray jsonArrReservations = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
            JSONObject objectInArray = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrReservations.length(); i++) {
                objectInArray = jsonArrReservations.getJSONObject(i);
                Iterator key = objectInArray.keys();

                while (((Iterator<?>) key).hasNext()) {
                    String k = key.next().toString();
                    Log.e("MyJSON", "Key: " + k + " Objeto: " + objectInArray.getString(k));
                    objectInArray = jsonArrReservations.getJSONObject(i);
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MyJSON", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys, muchas gracias por la corrección, en efecto solo obtenía el primer objeto {, , ,}, y solucione mi problema obteniendo primero los valores de cada etiqueta que necesitaba de mi json y posteriormente añadirlos a un ArrayList.
`
`